# Access server in local network through domain

Tags: networking, router, caddy

i have problem with access to server with domains.

Test url: testpage.example.com.

Server is in local network with port fowarding (80, 443), configured as web server using caddy server as reverse proxy.

**Case 1** (using Asus router)**:**
Connected on local network behind router. Server is in the same network as my computer. Everything works like a charm in and out of my network.

**Case 2** (using internet provider router)**:**
Connected on local network behind router. Can't access server with domain. Works with direct IP. Outside network, works as in case 1.

I used same server.

Does anyone know why this problem occured? How can i solve it?

Thanks,
David

Comment: What are your DNS settings in either scenario? In Case 2, are the requests failing because the hostname is resolving to an unexpected address or because it's not resolving to any address?

Comment: Because it's not resolving my domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options I can think of:

1. You could add a record to whatever DNS server you're using in Case 2.
2. You could write a short script that runs whenever you change network connections to modify your `hosts` file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the server you are trying to reach "testpage.example.com" resolves to your router's external IP address. Because your public IP address is the same as server's IP address (even though inside your home network you have different private IP addresses) your requests are lost in the ether.

As a workaround you can resolve the testpage.example.com manually on your local machine.
For Windows c:\windows\system32\etc\hosts
For Linux /etc/hosts
testpage.example.com 192.168.1.102 -> private IP of the machine serving the site.

Comment: Yes, i know i can use hosts. But thats not a good way, because on laptop its sometimes inside, sometimes outside our local network. Its waste of time  changing hosts all the time.
And this solution does not solve trouble on mobile phones (you can't change hosts if phone is not jail-broken).